# Error when merging two 2D arrays Zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a binary text classification task and I've applied the vectorizer on my data as follows:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokens)
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(docs_train.data)
print X_train_counts.shape
(150, 370)
```

and because I want to take only a random sample from class '0' (a in my example)and classify it with class '1', I did the following:

```
x =  X_train_counts
y =  docs_train.target

a_x,a_y=x[y==0,:],y[y==0]   
b_x,b_y=x[y==1,:],y[y==1]

inds=np.random.choice(range(a_x.shape[0]),50)
random_x=a_x[inds,:]
random_y=a_y[inds]

x_merged=np.concatenate((random_x,b_x))
y_merged=np.concatenate((random_y,b_y))
X_train,y_train=shuffle(x_merged, y_merged, random_state=0)
```

but I always getting the following error:

```
x_merged=np.concatenate((random_x,b_x))
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

although when I print the shape it gaves me:

```
print random_x.shape
print b_x.shape
(50, 370)
(50, 370)
```

any idea how to fix it ? with of course preserving the indexes as it links to the labels.

**Update:**
This is a print of the content/type of each arrays when the following commands executed:

```
print random_x[:5,:].toarray()
print b_x[:5,:].toarray()
print (type(random_x))
print (type(b_x))

[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [4 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

Comment: Print a bit of both arrays so we can see what is inside. Post the exact print please. I'm thinking its not about about the shape, but about type, or dimensions.

Comment: I've updated the question with the content/ type of each array ... thanks

Comment: It's the type that it's incompatible with the concatenate function. I've given an official answer to solve the problem (well.., I think).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Apparently Scipy has it's own concatenate methods including [hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html#scipy.sparse.hstack) and [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.vstack.html#scipy.sparse.vstack) which deal with sparse matrices.

The problem is indeed the type. To solve it just convert your csr_matrix into an array, concatenate, and than convert it again to a csr_matrix:

```
     import numpy as np
     import scipy.sparse as m
     a = np.zeros((50, 370))
     b = np.zeros((50, 370))

     am = m.csr_matrix(a).toarray()
     bm = m.csr_matrix(b).toarray()
     cm = m.csr_matrix(np.concatenate((am,bm)))
     print(am.shape,bm.shape,cm.shape)
```

The result is:

```
     (50, 370) (50, 370) (100, 370)
```

Comment: Sorry, actually it didn't work.. it doesn't give me the same shape at the end ... your program maybe works because a and b are both numpy arrays.. However, what about adding the following code to concatenate the two arrays : `x_merged=sp.vstack((random_x, b_x), format='csr')` .. does it give what is expected? .. I mean in terms of preserving the link between the matrix and the labels array 'random_y & b_y'

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. I wasn't expecting to be loss of information in the conversion. Sorry about that. Check the links (in the answer) for Scipy implementation of hstack and vstack.